# Unchecked lastError value: Error: No matching window - I get this error when trying to execute script with command in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this part of code (everything is in background.js), which basically executes javascript in pages based on page's URL. It should work on toolbar button click, and Ctrl + Q command.

I assign it to button click like this, and it works:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
browser.tabs.query(
        {active:true},
        function(tabs) {
            var tab = tabs[0];

            if(tab.url.indexOf("app.fillz.com/orders/edit") != -1){
                chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                    file: "fillz.js"
                });
            } else if(tab.url.indexOf("amazon") != -1 && tab.url.indexOf("buy/addressselect/handlers/display.html") != -1){
                chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                    file: "amazon.js"
                });
            }
        }
);
});
```

Problem is when I try to assign that same code to the onCommand event, like this:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
if (command == "fills2amazonCopyAndPaste") {
    browser.tabs.query(
            {active:true},
            function(tabs) {
                var tab = tabs[0];

                if(tab.url.indexOf("app.fillz.com/orders/edit") != -1){
                    console.log("FILLZ");
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                        file: "fillz.js"
                    });
                } else if(tab.url.indexOf("amazon") != -1 && tab.url.indexOf("buy/addressselect/handlers/display.html") != -1){
                    console.log("AMAZON");
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                        file: "amazon.js"
                    });
                }
            }
    );
}
});
```

Command is recognized, also the url of currently active tab, I checked it with those two console.log() commands in code above, but scripts don't get executed when I try to do it with command. In Browser Console, there is only this error:

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: No matching window
```

originating from: //gre/modules/ExtensionUtils.jsm

What could be the problem, I know my manifest.json file is alright as command gets recognized, but it simply won't execute javascript...

Comment: Thank you for having code in your question. However, particularly for debugging, we like to be able to test the answers we provide. That means we need to be able to duplicate the problem and then make changes that are verified to solve the problem. It is *vastly* easier to do so if you provide a *complete* [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you are seeing. When you don't do so, we have to put out significantly more effort just to begin helping you. That will significantly reduce the pool of people who will do so. It also means we have to *guess* at what the rest of the code should be.

Comment: I have down-voted this question because it does not contain a complete [mcve]. At a *minimum*, it does not contain your *manifest.json* file. Without that file included in the question, there is no possible way for anyone to come to the solution which you have in the answer you posted to this question. As such, the question has little value to anyone viewing it in the future. If you update the question to include a [mcve], I will remove my down-vote. If you do, please leave a comment with `@Makyen` so I am notified of the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem, it was the missing "all_urls" permission.
Apparently "tabs" and "activeTab" permissions weren't enough.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is what is produced when you attempt to inject into a tab for which you do not have permission to inject.  This could be a normal tab, if you do not have appropriate `permissions` set in your *manifest.json*. More commonly it is that you are attempting to inject into a tab containing a page into which it is not permitted to inject.  This includes most `about:*` pages (notably `about:debugging` from which add-ons are loaded as Temporary add-ons), but also now includes pages on AMO (e.g. `https://addons.mozilla.org`).

In addition your code does not definitively test the active tab *in the current window* for the URL you are testing. Effectively, this means that you may be trying to inject into a tab which you have not checked the URL matches one you want.

You do the following:

```
function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
```

This makes the assumption that the array of [`tabs.Tab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/Tab) returned by [`tabs.query()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query) will have the active tab for the current window as the first object in that array when you have asked for all `active:true` tabs. While the assumption may be correct in most cases, it is not guaranteed that it is a valid assumption. If you have multiple windows open you will have multiple active tabs. The order of those tabs in the array is not guaranteed to have the one for the current window first. You probably should change your queryInfo object to be `{active:true,currentWindow:true}`.

As it is, you may be attempting to inject into a tab which is not the active tab in the current window.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will consider those advises for change of code, but the error was in missing "all_urls" permission in manifest.json file!

Comment: @kecman, By what magic are we supposed to be able to know the content of your *manifest.json* file is incorrect when you have not provided your *manifest.json* file in the question?  This is *exactly* why a **complete** [mcve] is required for debugging questions to be on-topic for stackoverflow.